# How to add Windows Defender exclusion from Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-defender

I am currently working on many computers where I must add exclusions from a Linux USB (Preferably by a script I am making) to the windows PC.

I tried using chntpw but it does not show the registy keys I need.

Does anyone know of any way I could do such a thing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you see with chntpw? You need to find the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths`.

Comment: To the "Bot" I quite clearly specified I am attempting to add exclusions to windows defender from Linux. It is for monitoring software for my company.


@harrymc Thanks for giving a good response! When I get to Microsoft, there are just 2 keys without any sub-keys!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: The “Bot” message indicated the details were lacking, such as in the question posed by harrymc. You gave the program you used. You did not give the command line or search options, any errors, or the version of Windows.

Comment: Ah I see. I thought Windows 10 would be assumed by default, and theres only one command able to be used on chntpw for regedit. Sorry about that.

Comment: Windows 11 is quite common and too many people are still running Win7. Since you did not specify desktop, Windows Server 2016 and 2019 are also possibilities. Server 2012 is still supported for a few more months. If there was only one possible search option, how did harrymc’s comment help?

Comment: Actually I discovered the exclusions hiding in a slightly different path. "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\exclusions\Paths"